# How come I have 3 silver badges?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

How did I get 3 silver badges? Please see the screenshots below.

[image]

Now watch this: I only have one silver badge.

[image]

Comment: Those three badges are here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5456160/chirag-parmar?tab=badges on the main site...

Comment: But how did 3 come? If it is less that is understood. But if i never get 3 how could it be stored in cache?

Comment: @JonClements - yeah..correct. But how come it's hidden?? not showing anywhere?

Comment: @ChiragParmar it's not - they're not really trackable badges (or pointless when tracked) - eg you can't track the point when an election comes up or whether you'd vote and a yearly badge is well - not really worth bothering tracking as you can see how long you've been a member in your profile anyway... while the S&W badge is measurable by certain metrics...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the following silver badges:

- [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent?userid=5456160), awarded 1 hour ago
- [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white?userid=5456160), awarded Nov 15 at 14:29
- [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=5456160), awarded Nov 8 at 13:01

Note that not all badges show up in the "Select your next badge" window, because not all badges are trackable.